# Extract network range and subnet of an interface from a Linux machine

Tags: shell, awk, sed, scripting, grep

```
$ ip a 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:01:0a:80:00:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.128.0.6/32 brd 10.128.0.6 scope global noprefixroute dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 2327sec preferred_lft 2327sec
    inet6 fe80::4001:aff:fe80:6/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have tried the command below but I would want to replace the last octet with "0"

```
ip a | grep ": eth0" -A 2 |  grep inet | awk '{print $2}'
10.128.0.6/32
```

expected output

> 10.128.0.0/32

**Note:-**
ip address the last octet is more than one digit, for example, the last octet could be of a minimum of one digit and a maximum of three

```
10.128.0.6
10.128.0.16
10.128.0.116
```

so basically we need to replace "0" with the string between "\"

Comment: the `\.[0-9]+/` pattern is quite unique, you can replace it with `.0/`, eg via `sed`.

Comment: but bear in mind that when the mask is not a multiple of eight, you'll have a hard time masking the bits .. whatever you're trying to achieve..

Comment: I needed the network range and subnet for NFS export, every time a new nfs deployment should pick the network range and subnet properly 

`echo /nfs 10.128.0.0/32(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)" |sudo tee -a /etc/exports`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following(since there are no samples for `ip a` command mentioned by OP so couldn't test it).

***EDIT:*** As per OP's request adding one liner form of solution which will save value into a variable too:

```
value=$(ip a | awk '/: eth0/{found=1} found && /inet/ && !count{match($2,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/);val=substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/[0-9]+\//,"0/",$2);print substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH);count=1}')
```

Output will be as follows.

```
10.128.0.0/32
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this to just extract ip :

```
ip -o a | grep -oP "eth0\s+inet\s+\K\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/\d+"
```

Like this to full requirements :

```
ip -o a |
  perl -lne 'print "${1}0${2}" if m!enp0s31f6\s+inet\s+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.)\d+(/\d+)!'
```

Comment: $ ip -o a | grep -oP "eth0\s+inet\s+\K\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/\d+"
10.128.0.6/32


but it doesn't replace the last octet of the IP Address with "0"